# scipy pearson coefficient apparently parallelize computations spontaneously

Tags: python, scipy

I have the following script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as sts

def corr_funct(X, res, tau_vals):

    for z, tau in enumerate(tau_vals):
        x = X[:-tau]
        y = X[tau:]
        r, p = sts.pearsonr(x, y)
        res[z, 1] = r

    return res

my_list = [x for x in range(10**6)]
tau_max = 10**5

tau_vals = sorted(list(set(np.geomspace(1, tau_max, num=10**4, dtype=int))))
res = np.zeros((len(tau_vals), 2))
res[:, 0] = tau_vals

print('go for computations')

res = corr_funct(my_list, res, tau_vals)

np.save('my_res.npy', res)
```

The problem is as follows: when I launch it, everything is fine. When it 'goes for computation' and calls `corr_funct()` it happens the following: `top` tells me there is one program running:

[image]

If instead I look at `htop` I see numerous threads launched:

[image]

The processes are sleeping, but I was told it can slow down computation. I don't understand what is happening.

To make things even weirder, I have noted that if I replace

```
def corr_funct(X, res, tau_vals):

    for z, tau in enumerate(tau_vals):
        x = X[:-tau]
        y = X[tau:]
        r, p = sts.pearsonr(x, y)
        res[z, 1] = r

    return res
```

with

```
def corr_funct(X, res, tau_vals):

    z = 0
    for tau in tau_vals:
        x = X[:-tau]
        y = X[tau:]
        r, p = sts.pearsonr(x, y)
        res[z, 1] = r
        z += 1

    return res
```

the weird behavior does not (seem to) happen anymore. I have absolutely no clue about what is going on but I can't see anything wrong with my code and that fact that it seems to be due to `enumerate` makes things even weirder to me.

I am not novel to the use of `enumerate`, however I am wondering: is it possible that it causes this weird behavior?

**EDIT 1.1** I simplified a little the example

**EDIT 1.2** The behavior happens even if I remove `enumerate`. It just seems to be "less likely" to happen. Weirder and weirder to me...

**EDIT 2** The behavior seems (this findings seems very robust) to be due to `scipy.stats.pearsonr(x,y)`. Does anyone expert on scipy know why?

**EDIT 3** The output of `np.show_config` is the following:

```
np.show_config()
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blis_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
```

I personally ignore its meaning.

Comment: Interesting observation, thanks. Do you have any guesses about the consequences of this fact?

Comment: `scipy` uses `numpy` under the hood, which is optimized to take advantage of multithreading and multiprocessing.

Comment: Show the output of `np.show_config()`.  That will tell you about the underlying BLAS library that your installation of numpy is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SciPy uses NumPy, and both SciPy and NumPy depend on an underlying BLAS library.

From the output of `numpy.show_config()`, we see that your installation of NumPy is using the [OpenBLAS](http://www.openblas.net/) library.  To change the number of threads used by OpenBLAS, change the environment variable `OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS`.  E.g. see if setting `OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1` gives you serial behavior.

You can do that from within your Python script with

```
import os

os.environ['OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS'] = 1
```

From outside Python, it will depend on the OS that you are using.  For example, in Linux or Mac OS, to set the environment variable just for Python command being run, you could use

```
$ OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1 python myscript.py
```

Search for "setting environment variables" for more information.

If setting `OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS` doesn't work, try setting `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1`.

Read more about it at https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/blob/develop/README.md#setting-the-number-of-threads-using-environment-variables.

Comment: It worked, thank you. I did it by `import os os.environ["OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS"] = "1"`. If this is a standard way of doing it and is not problematic, write it in the answer and I'll accept it. Again, thank you.

Comment: What platform are you using?  Linux?

Comment: `>>> os.name
'posix'
>>> platform.system()
'Linux'`

Comment: Will the code be more efficient if I let the number of threads be greater than 1? Say 4...